# How to include jquery-ui file in webpack?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webpack

**Desired Behaviour**

Include jQuery UI in webpack build.

**Actual Behaviour**

Error when running webpack:

> ERROR in ./src/js/jquery-ui.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'jquery' in 'C:\Me\Documents\my_repo\src\js'

**What I've Tried**

I tried adding this to `webpack.config.js` but it didn't change anything:

```
plugins: [
   new UglifyJsPlugin(),
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "./jquery-3.3.1",
        jQuery: "./jquery-3.3.1",
        jquery: "./jquery-3.3.1"
    })
]
```

I also tried adding this to `webpack.config.js` (so that the path is relative to location of `webpack.config.js`) and that caused additional errors `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/js/jquery-3.3.1'`:

```
plugins: [
   new UglifyJsPlugin(),
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "/src/js/jquery-3.3.1",
        jQuery: "/src/js/jquery-3.3.1",
        jquery: "/src/js/jquery-3.3.1"
    })
],
```

**Steps To Replicate**

1)  Go to jQuery UI [download builder](https://jqueryui.com/download/)
2)  Select the *following only* and download the file:

-- Version 1.12.1
-- Effects > "Effects Core"
-- Effects > "Slide Effect"
-- Theme > "No Theme"

In the unzipped folder, get the `jquery-ui.js` file.

Note:  I only need slide effect, not all of jQuery UI, hence the custom download.

**my_entry_file.js**

```
import './jquery-ui';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin"); 

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/my_entry_file.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "stage-0"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "less-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "url-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
            test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/jquery-3.3.1'),
            use: [{
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: '$'
            }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
       new UglifyJsPlugin(),
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "./jquery-3.3.1",
            jQuery: "./jquery-3.3.1"
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
    alias: {
        'uikit-util': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/uikit/src/js/util')
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jquery-3.1.1` exists where the webpack config file is?

Comment: may want to try adding to ProvidePlugin: `"window.jQuery": "jquery'"`,
      `"window.$": "jquery"` or possibly look at using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui

Comment: @MatheusSilva - `jquery-3.1.1` exists in `src/js` which is where `my_entry_file.js` exists.  Using the config file shown in original post, jQuery works fine.  I am just trying to add jQuery UI as well.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is not working, i'm just saying that `ProvidePlugin` is not being able to resolve jquery. Try adding the path from webpack config (where it is) to where jquery is. Are you getting what i'm saying?

Comment: Jquery-ui is not able to get jquery from the global scope, this means that jquery is not being resolved correctly on the provide plugin

Comment: The path to jquery has to be relative to where webpack.config.js is, not where my_entry_file is.

Comment: @MatheusSilva - thanks, i tried but it caused errors, have added attempt and output to original post.

Comment: @MatheusSilva - fyi, have added what I think is possible solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing jquery with `npm install jquery` and changing `webpack.config.js` to:

```
plugins: [
   new UglifyJsPlugin(),
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",  
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
],
```

and build completes and front end functionality is working.

So it seems it might have been related to user MatheusSilva's comment regarding path to jquery in `webpack.ProvidePlugin`.